# What is YCS in Online Tourism industry?

Tags: hotels, terminology

While checking Agoda's website I was able to see [Agoda YCS Portal](https://ycs.agoda.com/). I want to Know what is YCS ?
I feel that this is associated with Online Tourism.

Comment: YCS stands for Yield Control System.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Agoda's official press release](https://www.agoda.com/info/yieldplanet-partnership-0159.html):

> Hotels that partner with Agoda.com can also enjoy access to the custom-built **Yield Control System** (YCS 3.0). By partnering with Agoda.com, hotels can have their promotions marketed to a database of more than two million members via Agoda.com's targeted email newsletters. If they choose, hotels can also use the YCS to update their hotel's page across Agoda.com's multilingual web sites to tailor different promotions for different storefronts and demographics.

If you're a hotel owner you can try to register and use Agoda's system to help you optimize your income. Otherwise it's of not much use to the average tourist.